# Windows Form Tooltip won't display on datagridview on initial cell edit

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tooltip

I'm trying to display a tool tip on a datagridview as the user is editing the cell. My problem is that the tool tip isn't displaying when the cell is being edited for the first time. For example, if I type "=2*10" into the cell the tool tip doesn't display, *BUT* if I were to then leave the cell, re-enter, and continue typing then the tool tip shows up (with the correct text and in the correct location). So I'm wondering why the tool tip doesn't show up on the initial edit. Answers in C# are acceptable as well as changing the syntax between C# and VB is trivial. In this case, the variable 'obj' in the code refers to a datagridview object.

```
' obj is datagridview object 

' hide tool tip on Enter key press
If keyData = Keys.Enter Then
        ToolTip1.Hide(obj)
        obj.ShowCellToolTips = True

' Check if cell is empty
ElseIf (obj.Item(obj.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, obj.CurrentRow.Index).Value IsNot Nothing) Then
        Debug.Print(obj.Item(obj.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, obj.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString)

        ' Check if current cell starts with "="
        If obj.Item(obj.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, obj.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString.StartsWith("=") Then
            If obj.IsCurrentCellInEditMode Then

                Dim RowHeight1 As Integer = obj.Rows(obj.CurrentRow.Index).Height
                Dim CellRectangle1 As Rectangle = obj.GetCellDisplayRectangle(obj.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, obj.CurrentRow.Index, False)

                CellRectangle1.X += obj.Left
                CellRectangle1.Y += obj.Top 

                Dim displayPoint As Point = PointToScreen(New Point(CellRectangle1.X, CellRectangle1.Y))

                obj.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
                obj.ShowCellToolTips = False
                ToolTip1.Show("This is a test", obj, displayPoint)
            End If

        Else 
            ToolTip1.Hide(obj)
            obj.ShowCellToolTips = True
        End If
End If
```

Comment: Where is this code called from?  Is it in an event? Can has context?

Comment: When you do the initial edit is the cell's value Nothing?

Comment: @Sam, here is the function call header `Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message,                                               ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean`

Comment: Recreated it - give me a min :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having recreated your problem I can see that the call here:

```
obj.Item(obj.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, obj.CurrentRow.Index).Value
```

Is not retrieving the value you expect.  It is providing the unedited value, the value that is saved after edit/validation.

If you change this call (in *all* places) to be:

```
obj.Item(obj.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, obj.CurrentRow.Index).EditedFormattedValue
```

it works great.

Comment: good question. I've stepped through it and it reads the cell as `Nothing` after I type the '=' sign, but thereafter for each character I press the code inside the If statements is in fact being executed. When looking at the datagridview as I step through I can even see an outline of the tool tip showing as though the code in fact worked, but once the function is completed it remains unseen.

Comment: That it does!! Thanks for the help, much appreciated!! `EditedFormattedValue` is a member I was unfamiliar with, but it's exactly what I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem and welcome to StackOverflow.  This answer tipped me over 1k rep - yay :D  Have a great day!